# TXS0102 level translator, problem connecting to external lines outside

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, bidirectional

I have a [TXS0102](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf) bidirectional level shifter connected to some external lines (RJ45 connector with cat 3 cable). The external lines have too much capacitance and it prevents the level translator from switching properly with fast enough rise times (I also have some ESD diodes not shown that also add some capacitance).

[image]

Part of the problem with these type of level translators is the 1-shot detection for bidirectional level shifting that they use which must have a fast enough rise time to facilitate switching, since I don't know how long the cable will be an the corresponding rise times and capacitance (not determined by my part of the design), I can't use the TXS0102 or anything like it that uses simmilar one-shot detection schemes.

I need to be able to do level translation to 1.8V or 3.3V to 5V that is bidirectional. How would I do that without using the level translators that use the 'one shot detection'?

(note, my current fix is to use a schmitt trigger, but that's not bidirectional)

Speed is not important, need at least 100kHz. I don't have direction control available. The signals are mostly inputs, but I want the option to be able to do an output for compatibility. The device on the other end could be just about anything, as there are many products that can be plugged into this interface.

Comment: Almost always the correct answer is "don't use these things". They're finicky and barely work for their intended purpose (board level bidirectional translation). Three questions: 1. why are you using unshielded cable for single-ended logic signals? 2. do you have a direction control signal handy? 3. you have unused pair(s), can those not be used for one-way signals?

Comment: Please edit your question and add details of what's on the other end of the cable, what they're communicating bi-dir (any protocols), with what and at what speeds. These ICs are fine and reliable within a PCB coming from a push-pull driver but can't drive and certainly no good for driving cables at speed. In design, their datasheet's internal block/circuit diagram must be examined very carefully to see if they'll suit the circuit. I used a load on a reasonably high speed control system. They're alright if used with care but often get seen as 'magic level shifters', leading to bad consequences.

Comment: (The problem probably is that the on-shot times out before the voltage has reached the high level.) Your labels GPIOx_TO_MCU imply that the MCU's GPIO pins are configured for the correct direction, i.e., the MCU always knows the direction. So you do not need a bidirectional level shifter (with all its limitations), but can use a transceiver/direction-controlled level shifter, e.g., (SN)74LVC2T45.

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but if you want to stop using bidirectional level shifters with accelerators, why not change to use bidirectional level shifters without accelerators?

Comment: I need a bidirectional level shifter regardless of the labels. The schematic was something I mocked up really quick to demonstrate the problem I have.

Comment: @TimWilliams Not my choice, I don't dictate what the cables will be. I don't have direction control (thought about that one). I have no more GPIO I can use.

Comment: @TonyM Edited I don't really have a fast bus so speed isn't an issue

Comment: @Justme Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @VoltageSpike Depends on situation. You could just use a discrete FET. Or an I2C level translator IC which basically integrates the FETs. Or if the MCU has 5V tolerant IO, nothing is needed.

Comment: Would an open-collector bus be acceptable then? Without a defined use, and without a defined cable, I would just as well strike the requirement, it's one less EMC issue to work around. If it has a partial definition, then I suggest pushing back on wherever the requirement is coming from until they can define it well enough to propose a reasonably correct solution. Such a partial definition should never have been signed off on in the first place, but perhaps that oversight can still be corrected. In any case it sounds like the solution here is not electrical but managerial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100 kHz is slower than Fast-mode I²C, so you can use any I²C translator.

The cheapest solution is the LSF0102/PCA9306, which is the equivalent of the common discrete FET I²C shifter (it just has three FETs inside).

If you fear that the MCU is too weak to drive the external lines, use an I²C buffer like the PCA9509/TCA9509. (This one has a voltage offset on the A side; many other buffers have a voltage offset on the B side, which might not be a good idea if you do not know what is connected.)

If the external capacitance can exceed the I²C limit of 400 pF, consider an I²C extender like the P82B96 or P82B715.